# How to order reverse to data table in table?

Tags: jquery, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm fetching data to my firebase and display to table inside table. I get the data by each. I use `orderByChild('id')`, but it's display smaller id first. I need to sort greater to smaller.

I create different table for each data.

```
var database = firebase.database();
database.ref("players").orderByChild('id').once('value', function(snapshot) {
      if (snapshot.exists()) {
        var content = '';
        snapshot.forEach(function(data) {
          var val = data.val();
          var pet = val.NewZaman.substring(12, 19);
          var pet2 = val.NewZaman.substring(0, 11);
          content += '<table class="filmlermob-table">';
          content += '<tr>';
          content += '<th colspan="3">' + val.Oynayanlar + '</th>';
          content += '</tr>';
          content += '<tr>';
          content += '<td data-th="filmtarih">' + pet2 + pet + '</td>';
          content += '<td data-th="filba" style="background: #f7f7f7;"><p class="nams">' + val.filba+ '</td>';
          content += '<td data-th="filmkanal">' + val.filmkanal+ '</td>';
          content += '</tr>';
          content += '</table>';
        });

        $('#filmler-table').append(content);

      }
```

Html

```
<table id="filmler-table" class="table">

</table>
```

**Edit**

I use

```
 function kontole() {





    var db = firebase.database();
  var updates = {};

  db.ref().child('players').once('value', function(snapshot) {
    snapshot.forEach(function(childSnapshot) {
      var childKey = childSnapshot.key;
      var childData = childSnapshot.val();
      console.log(childData);
      updates[childKey + '/sortingId'] =
        parseInt(childSnapshot.val().id, 10) * -1;
    });
    db.ref().update(updates);

});
}
```

Comment: Can you show your data model? Which kind of values are you storing in id? Number? Firebase auto-generated unique ids? Alphanumeric string?

Comment: Updated first message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is better to rely on the database (back-end) to sort your data than to rely on your front-end (especially if you have a large number of records).

While in Firestore you can sort in ascending or descending order (See https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/order-limit-data) this is not possible in the Realtime Database (`orderByChild()` only sorts in ascending order).

Since `id` is a numeric value, one possible approach for the Realtime Database is to duplicate your data and store the additive inverse of the id value (i.e. `id` value multiplied by -1 ) in an extra field, named e.g. `sortingId`.

Then your query will look like:

```
database.ref("players").orderByChild('sortingId').once('value', function(snapshot) {...}))
```

---

To update all your existing data, use the following JavaScript code:

```
  var db = firebase.database();
  var updates = {};

  db.ref('players').once('value', function(snapshot) {
    snapshot.forEach(function(childSnapshot) {
      var childKey = childSnapshot.key;
      var childData = childSnapshot.val();
      console.log(childData);
      updates['/players/' + childKey + '/sortingId'] =
        parseInt(childSnapshot.val().id, 10) * -1;
    });
    db.ref().update(updates);
  });
```

Comment: How to add 'sortingId' all child in one time and how I incrase.

Comment: @Dorbagna can you add to your question the code you use to create an item?

Comment: I thinkg I found a way.I use "orderByChild('id').limitToFirst(1)." to when I get the data.So I simply call the child that has a smallest number. Then I use "myref.child("id").set(biggestnumber);" and "biggestnumber =  parseInt(biggestnumber )-1; Than click the button and call second.Is there a any other simple way ?

Comment: @Dorbagna Sorry it is not 100% clear what you mean. Do you want to know how to update existing data or how to write the two values for new data?

Comment: I can use both.But I think I update existing data first.Than I'll need to write new data.

Comment: I'm going to commute now. I'll update my answer with a solution later on today. However, I would need that you share the code you use for writing new data, in order to adapt it. Please update your question with this code.

Comment: @Dorbagna See the update. For new data it is quite simple: use the same method you use to write the value of `id`.

Comment: It's didn't work.I updated my first message.I want to add I 'sortingId' for each existing 'players' child.So I'll could use 'sortingId' instead of 'id' for sorting.I hope I'm clear enough.

Comment: It's work only root child's.So when I tried 'players' It's didn't work.

Comment: @Dorbagna I've updated the answer to update the `players` node.